# trouble with linked list bubble sort

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I am a beginner learning to make bubble sort work with linked lists. I saw a geeksforgeeks page talking about this (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort-for-linked-list-by-swapping-nodes/), and adapted to my circumstances. I've gotten the code to work properly, but I have trouble understanding how logic works in this sorting. To my understanding "head" acts as base point, it always indicates the first node. But to my knowledge the head pointer should always move with the node (if node a and b are swapped, and head points to a, then head would continue pointing to a, even after the swap), this seems to contradict the first statement.

here is my code:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int Nid;
    char Nname[9];
    int Ngrades;
    struct Node *next;
}NODE;

int bubbleSortID(NODE** head, int count){
    NODE** h;
    NODE* temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        h = head;
        for (int j = 0; j < count-1; j++) {
            NODE* p1 = *h;
            NODE* p2 = p1->next;
            if (p1->Nid > p2->Nid) {
                temp = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                p1->next = temp;
                *h = p2;
            }
            h = &(*h) -> next;
        }
    }
}

void getID(NODE *head){ //used to print result
    while (head != NULL){
        printf("%d %s %d \n", head->Nid, head->Nname, head->Ngrades);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

given input:
10355112 jack 80
10311103 tom 85
10355107 zenry 70
10355014 tim 95
10355123 mary 85
11355123 helloo 1000

expected output:
10311103 tom 85
10355014 tim 95
10355107 zenry 70
10355112 jack 80
10355123 mary 85
11355123 helloo 1000
```

can someone help me understand what is going on in this code?

Comment: Need info about the NODE struct

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort-for-linked-list-by-swapping-nodes/

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including given input and expected output.

Comment: I added my NODE struct and expected input/output

Answer (score 0):

> To my understanding "head" acts as base point, it always indicates the first node.

Yes, but don't confuse this `head` variable with another variable, `h`, which is not intended to always (indirectly) point at the first node.

Also note that when `h = &(*h) -> next;` is executed, `h` and `head` are no longer the same pointer, and `*h` is no longer the first node of the list. `h` has then become the address of the `next` pointer of the node that precedes the node that will be referenced by `p1` in the next iteration.

> to my knowledge the head pointer should always move with the node (if node a and b are swapped, and head points to a, then head would continue pointing to a, even after the swap),

True, and that is why `*h = p2` is executed, so that `*h` is guaranteed to point to the node that has the lesser value, and does not stick to what it was before the swap. This becomes the invariant after the `if` block: whether or not that block was executed, `*h` refers to the node behind the other node that was used in the comparison, and they are in their right order.

Comment: thank you for your reply. it clarified my doubts in regards to the h variable. I'd like to ask about the purpose of the statement "h = head;" doesn't this reset h to what head initially points to? which could mean the node that head initially  pointed to even after it had been swapped

Comment: *assigning* directly to a variable, never affects what it previously referenced. The swap happened to what `h` referred to, but by assigning a new reference to `h` (with `h = head`) we just change `h` (the variable), not `*h` (the memory location that has a node pointer).